# how can i fetch data without refresh page using javascript & django?

Tags: javascript, django

i am using django to make API and get data with javasctipt. first time i'm using javascript i don't have very good understanding with javasctipt. i want to get data without refreshing page i am using javacript to fetch data form API. my code is getting data from databse only when i refresh the page. is there way to get data without refreshing page? when anybody create new post then page automatically load the post in index page without refresh the page?

index.html

```
<script>
    const Story = document.getElementById('stories');
    const Url = 'http://localhost:8000/api/';

    async function getPosts() {
        await fetch(Url)
            .then((res) => res.json())
            .then((data) => {
                data.map((post, index) => {
                    Story.innerHTML += `
                <div class="card card-body mb-3">
                  <h3>${post.title}</h3>
                </div>
              `;
                });
            })
            .catch((err) => console.log(err))
    }
    var timer = setInterval(getPosts,3000)
    getPosts();
</script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without getting into the more complex world of things like `WebSocket`, the simplest way is to put `getPosts();` into a `setInterval` and have it run the function every X seconds. This will rerun the function even if no new posts have been made but its the easiest.

The below code will run getPosts on load and every 3 seconds (3000 miliseconds)

```
<script>
    const Story = document.getElementById('stories');
    const Url = 'http://localhost:8000/api/';

    async function getPosts() {
        await fetch(Url)
            .then((res) => res.json())
            .then((data) => {
                Story.innerHTML = "";
                data.map((post, index) => {
                    Story.innerHTML += `
                <div class="card card-body mb-3">
                  <h3>${post.title}</h3>
                </div>
              `;
                });
            })
            .catch((err) => console.log(err))
    }

    var timer = setInterval(getPosts,3000)
    getPosts();
</script>
```

Comment: i don't understand how can i define this variable with this function would you like to tell me how can i use is? i am not vary good in javacript so please explain it .

Comment: @afi, have you tried the code or did you just update your answer?

Comment: i am try this code it's make request in every three seconds and it's loading old post in every three seconds.

Comment: @afi I updated my answer to include `Story.innerHTML = "";` before `data.map`.